# Why is there a newline on the end of my string when I finish decoding and encoding it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, base64

Here is my code:

```
def hex_to_base64(hex_string):
    clear = hex_string.decode("hex")
    print(clear)
    base64 = clear.encode("base64")
    print(base64)
    return base64

hexstring = "49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d"
result = hex_to_base64(hexstring)

# verify results
if result == 'SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t':
    print("Yuuuup!!! %r" % result)
else:
    print("Nope! %r" % result)
```

My results verification test is failing. It prints out:

```
Nope! 'SSdtIGtpbGxpbmcgeW91ciBicmFpbiBsaWtlIGEgcG9pc29ub3VzIG11c2hyb29t\n'
```

Where is the '\n' newline coming from? I could strip it off to get the test to pass, but I feel like that's cheating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Base64 encoding includes it:

```
>>> 'a'.encode('base64')
'YQ==\n'
```

Other Base64 encoding methods also include that newline; see [`base64.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.encode) for example:

> `encode()` returns the encoded data plus a trailing newline character (`'\n'`).

The choice appears to be historical; The MIME Base64 content-transfer-encoding dictates that a maximum line length is used and newlines are inserted to maintain that length, but [RFC 3548](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html#section-2.1) state that implementations must not.

Python offers both options; you *could* use the [`base64.b64encode()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) here instead:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode('a')
'YQ=='
```

Comment: This is exactly the information I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: The MIME Base64 content-transfer-encoding dictates that a maximum line length is used and newlines are inserted to maintain that length

Can you explain more? How the trailing newline maintain the length?

Comment: MIME additionally enforces a line length of 76 characters plus the CRLF.

when the string is large enough (say 100 bytes), should we insert CRLF in the middle of the output string or just add the trailing CRLF?

Comment: @Codefor: `str.encode()` and `base64.encode()` takes care of this for you; lines of 76 characters (not counting the newline) are produced.

Comment: Got it!Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to get the encoded string without the trailing newline the [`base64.b46encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) function will do that. Here's the difference:

```
In [19]: base64.encodestring('a')
Out[19]: 'YQ==\n'

In [20]: base64.b64encode('a')
Out[20]: 'YQ=='
```

Comment: Than you. Short but very useful answer